# Asp.Net Core 3.1 WebAPI with Asp-Net-Identity authorization failing

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-identity

I have a WebAPI designed for beeing used as Authentication Server that has an endpoint for registering users, another one for login in users and another one to get the user profile.

Register works correctly and login works good also aparently.

My problem is the following: The user profile endpoint needs Authorization so I use the token that login endpoint returns and append it to the request as bearer token. Requests always return 401: Unauthorized even though I am using the token that login returned.

I test the services with postman and it doesnt return any error with token, only says that I'm unauthorized to make that request.

This are the responses in Postman:

Login request:[image: Login with Postman]

UserProfile request: [image: UserProfile with Postman]

Here is the code:

Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        //Inject AppSettings
        services.Configure<ApplicationSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("ApplicationSettings"));

        services.AddMvc(option => option.EnableEndpointRouting = false).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Latest);

        services.AddDbContext<AuthenticationContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("IdentityConnection")));

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AuthenticationContext>();

        services.AddCors();

        // JWT Authentication

        var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["ApplicationSettings:JWT_Secret"].ToString());
        var signingKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key);

        services.AddAuthentication(x =>
        {
            x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            x.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        }).AddJwtBearer(x => {
            x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            x.SaveToken = false;
            x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = signingKey,
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateAudience = false,
                ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
            };
        });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseCors(builder =>
        builder.WithOrigins(Configuration["ApplicationSettings:Client_URL"].ToString())
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        );

        app.UseMvc();

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
```

ApplicationUserController (register and login endpoints):

```
{
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ApplicationUserController : ControllerBase
{
    private UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
    private readonly ApplicationSettings _appSettings;

    public ApplicationUserController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager, IOptions<ApplicationSettings> appSettings)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _appSettings = appSettings.Value;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("Register")]
    // POST: /api/ApplicationUser/Register
    public async Task<object> PostApplicationUser(ApplicationUserModel model)
    {
        var applicationUser = new ApplicationUser()
        {
            UserName = model.UserName,
            Email = model.Email,
            FullName = model.FullName
        };

        try
        {
            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(applicationUser, model.Password);
            return Ok(result);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("Login")]
    // POST: /api/ApplicationUser/Login
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginModel model)
    {
        var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.UserName);
        if (user != null && await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, model.Password))
        {
            var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
            {
                Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[]
                {
                    new Claim("UserId", user.Id.ToString())
                }),
                Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1),
                SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_appSettings.JWT_Secret)), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
            };
            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var securityToken = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
            var token = tokenHandler.WriteToken(securityToken);
            return Ok(new { token });
        }
        else
        {
            return BadRequest(new { message = "Username or password is incorrect" });
        }
    }
}
```

}

UserProfileController (getUserProfile endpoint):

```
{
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]

public class UserProfileController : ControllerBase
{
    private UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    public UserProfileController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize]

    //GET : /api/UserProfile
    public async Task<Object> GetUserProfile()
    {
        string userId = User.Claims.First(c => c.Type == "UserID").Value;
        var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
        return new
        {
            user.FullName,
            user.Email,
            user.UserName
        };
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help and if you need some extra info just tell me

Comment: Use sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and compare headers first request in Postman with first request in c#.  Make the c# headers look like the postman headers.

Comment: In the Postman screen shot, will you include the header information for `Accept` `Content-Type` and `Authorization`? Also, add a breakpoint and step through it to get the error message and post that.

Comment: I'm facing the some problem. Did you find a solution for that?